# ios addEventListener not working

Tags: javascript, ios, ecmascript-6, addeventlistener, arrow-functions

Why does this button not work on ios? It works fine on desktop and android. It works on ios if clickHandler is defined as a regular function.

http://codepen.io/CalebEverett/pen/RRmYgx

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            button {
                width: 150px;
                height 50px;
             }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="testdiv">it doesn't work</div>
        <button id="do">Button</button>
    </body>
    <script>
        const clickHandler = () => {
            document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML = "it works!"
        }
        document.getElementById("do").addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);
    </script>
<html>
```

Comment: Are you transpiling this, or is this the actual code you're sending to the browser? Many desktop and Android browsers won't support this either.

Comment: You probably have a nice error message in the console that will tell you it doesn't understand a word, BTW.

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility arrow functions are not quite widely supported yet.

Comment: this ecmascript 6 code. most browser dont support that.  you have to change the const to var and remove the arrow functions (" () => {}")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which is an ES6 feature.

Support for ES6 in general and arrow functions specifically is not yet widespread, and is limited to recent versions of some browsers only. Specifically, Safari does not support arrow functions on either Desktop (Mac) or mobile (iOS), but many other browsers will have the same issue (including older Android browsers, IE, etc.).

You'll have to either transpile your ES6 code to something that is supported more widely, or stick to more standard Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the response. https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ and https://babeljs.io/ were useful resources as well.